# On iPad, why does AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient stop the music playing in iPod?

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation

The following code is supposed to play a sound and won't stop the music playing by iPad's Music/iPod. (on iOS 5.1, the iPod app became the Music app).

It is using `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient` instead of `AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient`.  But it actually stopped the music in either case.  Is there something wrong with the use of `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient`?

```
NSURL *sound0URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"0" ofType:@"aiff"]];

audioPlayer0 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:sound0URL error:nil];

audioPlayer0.delegate = self;
[audioPlayer0 prepareToPlay];

NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:&setCategoryErr];

NSLog(@"%@", setCategoryErr);

audioPlayer0.currentTime = 0;
[audioPlayer0 play];
```

the `setCategoryErr` is printed as `(null)` so there should be no error.

Comment: What happens if you set the AVAudioSession category BEFORE you call [audioPlayer0 prepareToPlay];? Maybe something in prepareToPlay is actually stopping the iPod since the ambient category is not yet set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in my comment, it seems the solution is to set the AVAudioSession category BEFORE calling `prepareToPlay` on the AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: At first, I thought that I had set the category before I called prepareToPlay, so I didn't give a chance to this situation. But after seeing this answer I decided to re-check if I set the category before calling prepareToPlay. And I realised that I had not.